# How to let a raspberry pi 3b connect to wifi with wps from within a c program

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have a machine controlled by a raspberry pi. For servicing I want to connect the local wifi network. The machine has no controls with which you could enter ssid and password. With a combination of button pushes a connection to the wifi must be made.

In my program I have the following code:

```
    void start_Wps(void) {
      if (!fork()) 
        execl("wpa_cli","-i","wlan0","wps_pbc", NULL); 
    }
```

If I start my program from a ssh terminal it works most of the time. However when I let my code start from rc.local the rpi never connects to my wifi network.

Comment: Will the environment in which the machine operates always be the same? If so, do you have the chance to provision the Wi-Fi credentials before you take the machine into use? WPS is only required to exchange the credentials, so if it is just about triggering the connection, you could find an easier way...

Comment: In my experience my clients often buy new routers or change ssid and password.

Answer (score 1):

In case your project shall work in an enterprise environment, can you be sure that WPS is supported on the client’s access points?

Another thing to consider: WPS is in decline. It is not supported e.g. in Android since Android 9, WPA3 security won’t be supported by WPS and its successor has already been presented by Wi-Fi Alliance.

It is called “Wi-Fi Easy Connect” and it basically is a device provisioning protocol that also allows the connection of “headless” device, i.e. without display or input. You could connect your mobile phone to the Wi-Fi network on the customer’s premise, read the QR code that you previously put on your machine and then the phone takes care of connecting the machine to the network.

More detailed information is provided on Wi-Fi Alliance’s website: https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-easy-connect

If you want to make sure that your project is future-proof and will be maintainable for years to come, you might want to look into that.